# Circular loading Spinner in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to create loading spinner in jetpack compose. I don't have video but I have image how it looks like.

[image]

I only know about `CircularProgressIndicator` but I don't know how to customise and look like above image.

```
    CircularProgressIndicator(
            progress = progress,
            color = progressColor,
            strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

I found the video it looks like Twitter loading spinner in web. I made small video screenshot. Please have a look on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/-7vh7EoR5bE)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hello bro try this one and ans me.

```
@Composable
fun Indicator(
    size: Dp = 32.dp, // indicator size
    sweepAngle: Float = 90f, // angle (lenght) of indicator arc
    color: Color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary, // color of indicator arc line
    strokeWidth: Dp = ProgressIndicatorDefaults.StrokeWidth //width of cicle and ar lines
) {
    ////// animation //////

    // docs recomend use transition animation for infinite loops
    // https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation
    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

    // define the changing value from 0 to 360.
    // This is the angle of the beginning of indicator arc
    // this value will change over time from 0 to 360 and repeat indefinitely.
    // it changes starting position of the indicator arc and the animation is obtained
    val currentArcStartAngle by transition.animateValue(
        0,
        360,
        Int.VectorConverter,
        infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 1100,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        )
    )

    ////// draw /////

    // define stroke with given width and arc ends type considering device DPI
    val stroke = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        Stroke(width = strokeWidth.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Square)
    }

    // draw on canvas
    Canvas(
        Modifier
            .progressSemantics() // (optional) for Accessibility services
            .size(size) // canvas size
            .padding(strokeWidth / 2) //padding. otherwise, not the whole circle will fit in the canvas
    ) {
        // draw "background" (gray) circle with defined stroke.
        // without explicit center and radius it fit canvas bounds
        drawCircle(Color.LightGray, style = stroke)

        // draw arc with the same stroke
        drawArc(
            color,
            // arc start angle
            // -90 shifts the start position towards the y-axis
            startAngle = currentArcStartAngle.toFloat() - 90,
            sweepAngle = sweepAngle,
            useCenter = false,
            style = stroke
        )
    }
}
```

In short - a circle is drawn on the canvas and an indicator arc is drawn on top of it.

transitive animation cycles the value of `currentArcStartAngle` variable from 0 to 360 (this is the angle in the circle) and this variable is used to set the starting angle of the indicator arc

To better understand what the starting angle, do `useCenter = true` in `drawArc`

`currentArcStartAngle` is State, so each change causes the canvas to be recomposed and redrawn with new start angle

result:

[image]

Comment: Can you explain in detail what are you doing all these stuff?

Comment: @vivekmodi Done. I added comments and description

Answer (score 7):

You can draw another circle behind progress using `Modifier.drawBehind`

```
val strokeWidth = 5.dp

CircularProgressIndicator(
    modifier = Modifier.drawBehind {
        drawCircle(
            Color.Red,
            radius = size.width / 2 - strokeWidth.toPx() / 2,
            style = Stroke(strokeWidth.toPx())
        )
    },
    color = Color.LightGray,
    strokeWidth = strokeWidth
)
```

Comment: How to give width and height `17 x 16`?